# Integrating the product of two functions

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm a bit confused with the result of my following code:

```
import scipy.integrate as intg
Phi_0 = lambda x: x**4
Phi_1= lambda x:  x**2
f    = lambda x: Phi_0*Phi_1
I = intg.quadrature(lambda x: Phi_0(x)*Phi_1(x), -1, 1)
print("I =", I[0], "Tolerance =", I[1])
```

Which of course give the result.
But when I write the code for integration as any other method from below it gives an error:

```
 I = intg.quadrature(lambda x: Phi_0*Phi_1, -1, 1)
 I = intg.quadrature(f, -1, 1)
 I = intg.quadrature(f(x), -1, 1)
```

Can you explain why the first method works but not the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just multiply `Phi_0` and `Phi_1` - they are functions, and they need to be called with an argument:

```
f = lambda x: Phi_0(x) * Phi_1(x)
# Here ------------^----------^
```

Comment: I see. Thank you. But then why wouldn't it give an error when you run this code:  
 `f    = lambda x: Phi_0*Phi_1`

Comment: @gune that's how python works - there's nothing wrong with it syntacticly, so the definition succeeds, but when you try and run it it errors out because there's no `*` operator between two function references.